# Uniform Continuity on two separate intervals, but no on the union of the intervals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I'm just trying to find a function that is uniformly continuous on sets D1 and D2, but not on the union of D1 and D2. Thank you!

Comment: Note that if you can 'properly separate' the intervals, this is impossible, so this places a requirement on the sets $D_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try $D_1 = [0,1)$ and $D_2 = [1,2]$.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure!